# In exchangelib I get NoneType error when there are no emails

Tags: python, unix, exchangelib

In my python script I am trying to scan my inbox retrieve emails in reverse date-time order and by filtering on a subject. However, if my inbox has no emails with that subject, I get a `NoneType` error, `object` is not iterable" 
If there is an email with that subject, it all works fine. 
However when there is no email with that subject, I get this error. 
How to resolve it?

I have tried to use try catch blocks but the exception is not being caught

```
for item in account.inbox.all().filter(subject__contains='foo').order_by('-datetime_received')[:100]:
```

if there is no email with that subject, then there is a none type error.

if I check

```
if  (account.inbox.all().filter(subject__contains='foo').order_by('-datetime_received')[:100] is None):
print("none type error")
```

the `print` statement is not executed.

I would like to be able to skip the loop if there is no email at all in the mailbox

Comment: slicing `[:100]` can't give `None` so `if item is None` can't work. It can give only empty list and better use universal `if not item:`

Comment: you could also use `print()` to see what you have in variables `item` - maybe you get list with `[None, ...]`

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Please post the entire stack trace of the failure. Also, which exchangelib version is this?